# How to get PageRequest to work in spring boot with annotated query

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm upgrading from spring boot 1 to spring boot 2.

I'm trying to pick off the first result only.

```
PageRequest pageRequest = PageRequest.of(0, batchSize, Sort.Direction.ASC, "id");
```

With an annotated query on the repository

```
@Query("select c from Component")
List<Component> findReturnComponent(PageRequest pageRequest);
```

I'm getting this error message

```
but parameter 'Optional[pageRequest]' not found in annotated query 'select c from Component
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use Pageable Interface instead of PageRequest

```
Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(0, batchSize, Sort.Direction.ASC, "id");
```

and

```
@Query("select c from Component")
List<Component> findReturnComponent(Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: Thanks it's work for me. Why we should use Pageable interface instead of PageRequest?